Установка keyboard
Обновил pip, вылезает это:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\test\testfotest.py", line 9, in <module>
    turtle.exitonclick()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "<string>", line 6, in exitonclick
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\turtle.py", line 3699, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()
                     ~~~~~~~^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\turtle.py", line 3710, in __init__
    _Screen._root = self._root = _Root()
                                 ~~~~~^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\turtle.py", line 429, in __init__
    TK.Tk.__init__(self)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2459, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python313/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/test/.venv/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/test/lib/tcl8.6 C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/test/.venv/library C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/test/library C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/test/tcl8.6.14/library C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/tcl8.6.14/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly


python -m pip install --upgrade pip  обновите пип сперва‍♀️

Виртуальное окружение правильно настроено? Мб питон криво установлен

@Amgarak в плане криво? его можно как то криво установить? На счёт виртуального окружения не знаю, я новичок и это слово впервые слышу, возможно, дело в том что у меня комюнити версия PyCharm а не лицензионная

Для теста создайте новый проект и в настройках укажите новый путь до виртуального окружения. Он его пересоберёт и там уже посмотрим.

Это вообще не проблема pip или keyboard, а проблема с tkinter. Я предполагаю, что у вас Python 3.13. Попробуйте переустановить его, галку, обведенную красным на скриншоте по ссылке нужно убрать: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/125179#issuecomment-2403657261. Либо установите Python 3.12 вместо 3.13.

Я пару дней назад предупреждал о серьёзнейших проблемах с версией 3.13, не поленился вывести на обсуждение тему. Тему эту тут конечно же закрыли, она ведь не нужна и не интересна. Я откатился на 3.12.7 и Вам советую. Есть в 3.13 проблемы и похуже.
